# Postgresql - Optimizing creation of several indexes on one big table

Tags: postgresql, optimization, indexing

What's the best way to create multiple indexes on one very large table (hundreds of Gb).

Currently I have to execute queries like that

```
create index A on myBigTable (a) using btree ;
create index B on myBigTable (b) using btree ;
create index C on myBigTable (c) using btree ; 
....
```

It takes a very long time. PG has to read all the data from the table several times.

When index on column A is in creation, it prevents from creating an index on column B at the same time.

So, is there a way to optimize the time (and resources consumption) to create all indexes on the same table?

If not possible to really optimize currently, is it something planned for a near future?

Comment: `create index concurrently ...` will allow you to create all indexes at the same time (if issued from different connections)

Comment: Postgres 11 improved the time it takes to create the index as it can use a parallel scan on the table

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name , but are you sure ? with different connexion, when creating index with 'concurrently', I see that one index is being creating, and others are 'waiting' (wait_evt_typ = lock  // wait_evt = relation)